# How to register a COM class in memory?

Tags: winapi, com

I have a COM class (*e.g.*, `CLSID_WidgetFactory`) that I want to make available to anyone in my process who calls:

```
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Widget, ...);
```

But i want to make it available without having to register it, or include it in a registration-free COM assembly manifest.

### Core question

I have:

- a `clsid` (`CLSID_Widget`)
- an `IClassFactory` implementation

How can i register the these with the COM infrastructure so that anyone in my process can create the COM object?

Obviously I want to accomplish this:

- without registering the COM object in the `HKLM\Software\Classes` registry hive
- without registering the COM object in the `HKCU\Software\Classes` hive
- without create a [registration-free COM assembly manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739845/how-to-deploy-sql-server-compact-edition-4-0)

Conceptually i would have my classID, and my factory object:

```
class WidgetFactory : ComObject, IClassFactory
{
   //IClassFactory methods
   HRESULT CreateInstance(IUnknown unkOuter, Guid iid, out obj)
   {
      Widget widget = new Widget();

      HRESULT hr = widget.QueryInterface(iid, out obj);
      return hr;
   }
}
```

Then i want to register my class factory:

```
Guid CLSID_Widget = "{0677445E-EA9B-447A-AF2E-CCD86E49CED0}";
IClassFactory factory = new WidgetFactory();

RegisterClassFactory(CLSID_Widget, factory);
```

All that's left is to figure out how to register a COM Class in-memory:

```
void RegisterClassFactory(Guid clsid, IClassFactory classfactory)
{
   //...
}
```

### Search terms

- How to register a COM object in memory
- How to register a COM class in my process
- How to register a CLSID in memory
- How to register IClassFactory in my application

**Note**: I know the answer. But i can't figure out the correct set of search terms that would trigger a hit.

**Bonus Reading**

- [Can I create and use a COM class without registering it in the registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955791/can-i-create-and-use-a-com-class-without-registering-it-in-the-registry)
- Old New Thing: [Registration-free COM the old-fashioned way: The car mp3 player](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120406-00/?p=7913)
- Old New Thing: [How do I accept files to be opened via IDropTarget instead of on the command line?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100503-00/?p=14183)

Comment: Not entirely what you're looking for, but you may want to evaluate [Self-Registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694515.aspx) to see if it suits your needs.

Comment: @IInspectable: Self-Registration has NOTHING to do with this situation at all. All that does is informs interested parties that the COM module's registration code is implemented inside of the module itself instead of in an external installation script. A party can then call the module's exported `Dll(Un)RegisterServer()` function, or run the module with the `/(un)regserver` command-line switch, to invoke the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`CoRegisterClassObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693407(v=vs.85).aspx) with `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER` and `REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE`.

```
DWORD RegisterClassFactory(Guid clsid, IClassFactory factory)
{
   /*
      Register a COM class in-memory. 
      Any requests by COM to create object clsid will use the 
      class factory given by factory.
      This means that a COM object does not have to be registered
      in the registry in order to use it. Nor does it have
      to be included in an application manifest.

      Public domain: No attribution required.
   */
   DWORD dwCookie; //returned cookie can be later used to delete the registration

   HRESULT hr = CoRegisterClassObject(
         clsid,                // the CLSID to register
         factory,              // the factory that can construct the object
         CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, // can only be used inside our process
         REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE,   // it can be created multiple times
         out dwCookie          // cookie we can later use to delete the registration
   );
   OleCheck(hr);

   return dwCookie;
}
```

And now anyone in your process can create this arbitrary COM object (even though it isn't registered in the registry, and was not included in an assembly manifest):

```
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Widget, null, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUnknown, out unk);
```

If you're registering several classes, you can combine the [`REGCLS_SUSPENDED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679697(v=vs.85).aspx) flag (e.g. with the or operator `|`):

> Suspends registration and activation requests for the specified CLSID until there is a call to [**CoResumeClassObjects**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692686(v=vs.85).aspx). This is used typically to register the CLSIDs for servers that can register multiple class objects to reduce the overall registration time, and thus the server application startup time, by making a single call to the SCM, no matter how many CLSIDs are registered for the server.
>
> **Note**  This flag prevents COM activation errors from a possible race condition between an application shutting down and that application attempting to register a COM class.

and then call [`CoResumeClassObjects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692686(v=vs.85).aspx) once to register the classes atomically.

If you intend to perform this from a DLL, you should make sure the DLL provides an entry point for registration at the start of the application.  Or just don't use the resume and suspend class objects functions.

Comment: *I know the answer. But i can't figure out the correct set of search terms that would trigger a hit.* -- Thanks for improving the answer, I guess.  What's the purpose, to improve SEO on `CoRegisterClassObject` with other terms? Can't that be done on existing posts?

Answer (score 2):

[`CoRegisterClassObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693407) would register a class factory for given `CLSID` and make it available to callers of your process, however just in the apartment of registration (perhaps you could register in several apartments though).

`CoCreateInstance` elsewhere within apartment would succeed as if `CLSID` was registered through registry the usual way.

AFAIR you are interested in Delphi, but anyway [this](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Common/alax.info/roatlcom.h?rev=482#L2625) ATL C++ class is a sample code snippet that shows use of `CoRegisterClassObject` to temporarily register `CLSID` for third party `CoCreateInstance` in scope of local variable:

```
{
        BEGIN_OBJECT_MAP(g_pObjectMap)
            OBJECT_ENTRY(__uuidof(CSplitterMediaObject), CSplitterMediaObject)
            // ...
        END_OBJECT_MAP()
        CLocalObjectMap ObjectMap(g_pObjectMap, TRUE);
        // ...
        // Someone calls CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CSplitterMediaObject), ...
        // here and the call succeeds as if the class is registered
}
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Not only. With `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER` it can be used exactly for what is requested.